# PTIJ: Using electricity on Shabbos heter

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There is a common stance that one may not "use" (whatever that means) electricity on Shabbos, but it seems that the talmud allows for a heter, a permissible case. Apparently, if one wants to insert an electrical wire into an outlet on the sabbath using the lower of two sockets,

[image]

one can do so because of the principle of "low [plug](https://www.halacha2go.com/php/h2go/home2.php?number=665)."

Why is this allowance not employed more in Jewish households?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Simple: since the top one is assur, the bottom one is too. In other words, lo plug about the low plug.

Comment: My rav actually told me the top plug was allowed. Definitely would've kept differently if he hadn't. *shrug*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All prohibitions on Shabbos are learned out from what was done in the Mishkan. Since the boards for the Mishkan used sockets on the bottom, that is for sure going to be forbidden on Shabbos.
The law for sockets on *top* is less obvious; I'd guess it is a toldah of the av melacha, sokhet.

Answer (score 2):

You've completely misinterpreted the sugya. The heter derived from "lo plug" allows us to use a *gas stove* on Shabbat, since it does not have a plug at all.

Warning PURIM TORAH PLEASE PLEASE DO NOT USE A GAS STOVE ON SHABBAT!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: next thing is you're going to tell me it is about hair replacement...

Comment: Wut. No pilot light?

Comment: I am not Jewish but this warning seems excessive.

Comment: @user it is very serious for a Jew to use a gas stove on Shabbat and even more serious to cause one to think it's permitted to do so

Comment: @user253751 - its also a commandment to never lead another into error, for example by misleading them what is allowed or not - even if merely by example or by lack of clarity what one is doing. So if someone saw this page or a copy of it, and didn't realise it was in jest, and thought this was serious advice...... yes Judaism does take leading people wrongly, * that * seriously.........

Answer (score 2):

The only dialect of English in which the words plug and פלוג are pronounced the same way is Geordie, see

https://www.bl.uk/british-accents-and-dialects/articles/geordie-vowel-sounds#

http://sounds.bl.uk/resources/learning/soundsfamiliar/case-studies/geordie/vowels/geordie-STRUT.mp3?_ga=2.197809705.74350462.1614215770-203880178.1614215770

Geordie's are not smart enough to figure out whether they should use the top socket or the bottom socket.

Therefore the *chachamim* made a לא פלוג and said, just as you may not use the top socket, you may also not use the bottom socket. Hence, לא פלוג at all.